# Working with custom routes in wp-mvc plugin

Tags: wordpress, model-view-controller

I’ve been trying to develop large scale application in wordpress. Been through several plugin development best practices. And finally I’ve been reading the documentation of http://wpmvc.org/

I pretty much understood its automatic (mvc) code generation tools. Its default controller functions index() & show() works pretty well.

But, when I tried to add a custom_action(), thats where I got stuck.

```
class DemoController extends MvcPublicController {
    public function hello(){
        print_r($this->params);
        die();
    }
}
```

above function hello() is only accessible by below URL:

```
domain.com/demo/hello/{num}
```

but can’t be accessed via:

```
domain.com/demo/hello
```

Do I need to write any custom route to make this work? Or, am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution, and it was pretty easy.

In **config/routes.php**,

I replaced, this:

```
MvcRouter::public_connect('{:controller}/{:action}/{:id:[\d]+}');
```

with this:

```
MvcRouter::public_connect('{:controller}/{:action}');
```

**[ IMPORTANT ]** Don't forget to save permalinks to flush rewrite rules.